# Am I eligible for applying PMAY scheme?

Tags: india, first-time-home-buyer, government

I am planning to buy a home and my father already own a home. Am I eligible for applying [**PMAY** (Pradhan Mantri Awas Yojana-Housing for All (Urban))](https://pmaymis.gov.in/) scheme?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I added the “India” tag based on my understanding from google of PMAY scheme. If you are not in India or I have misunderstood please comment or edit.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pradhan_Mantri_Awas_Yojana), PMAY Schemes Eligibility criteria says:

> The beneficiary should **not** have an **own dwelling unit on the name of any family member in any part of India**

In short the answer for your question is ***NO***, you are not eligible for the scheme.

---

You can reach PMAY officials at the toll free numbers:

Gamin:-> 1800116446

Urban (NHB):-> 1800113377 OR 1800113388

Urban (HUDCO):-> 1800116163

Answer (score 1):

PMAY scheme will be implemented between 2015 - 2022 and the central govt will provide credit linked subsidy.

To get straight forward answer, you need to answer

1. Are buying house for you or for your father?
2. whether you are located in urban area?
3. What is the plinth area of the house you are going to buy?

Having a house in your father's name doesn't make you ineligible for PMAY scheme. There are other conditions. If you can answer above questions, i can help you.